# Installing Soap extension for PHP 8.1 issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap

I have PHP 8.1 installed in Ubuntu 18.04.06.

Now i am trying to install `soap` extension for PHP 8.1 using following command

`sudo apt install php8.1-soap`

But I get following error

```
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-soap
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-soap'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-soap'
```

I also tried adding, but same error

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php8.1-soap -y
sudo apt update
```

Is this because my Ubuntu version is old? How can i install `soap` extension compatible to php 8.1

Thanks

Comment: This is because  Ubuntu U18.04 is not supported. Try: 'add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php '/. Or update your version Ubuntu

Comment: Does `apt search php soap` show the package?

Comment: @brombeer Yes it shows but `php 5.6-soap` and `php7.0-soap` only

Comment: Strange. Have you installed PHP8.1 recently? Does `apt search php8.1` show the package `php8.1-common` (or any 8.1 package)? Could be you installed PHP8.1 some time ago but support for Ubuntu18.04 has been dropped, just a guess

Comment: try:'sudo apt install php8.1-dev'
'sudo pecl install soap'

Comment: @brombeer search gives many php8.1 packages including `php8.1-common`

Comment: @ЛюбомирГорбей I get same error  `Unable to locate package php8.1-dev`

Comment: update your version Ubuntu , otherwise you will have such problems in the future

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think you have not ppa:ondrej/php in your system. That's why you are getting this package not found error. You can learn below command

```
sudo apt update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php8.1-soap -y
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added that too, still not working

Comment: very strange situation.

Comment: Can you update your system or it is not possible?

Comment: Wouldn't OP already have `ppa:ondrej/php` to install PHP8.1?

Comment: ppa:ondrej/php is enough for installng all php extensions such as curl, zip, mbstring, intl, json, soap etc. But why your system don't getting extension, it is totally strange